# Numpy way of step forward for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, broadcast

I want to avoid for-loop with step in the following code and replace it with Numpy code to speed up the process:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[0,0,7,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,5,0]])

for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    for j in range(A.shape[1]-1):
        if A[i,j]==7 and A[i,j+1]==0:
            A[i,j+1]=7
```

I know how to do it with for-loop without step. Say, `A,B,C` are 2D arrays with same size, then this slow code:

```
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    for j in range(A.shape[1]):
        if A[i,j]==7 and B[i,j]==0:
            C[i,j]=7
```

...can be faster by the following single line numpy code:

```
C[(A==7) & (B==0)]=7
```

I guess it should be something similar, including `np.where` and `np.roll` functions? Appreciate your help!

Comment: It is easier to translate it to this: you need to convert ALL immediate zeros after 7s in the same row to 7.

Comment: No, it must be like this, because this is just a toy code of more complex code with 3D arrays, where sevens (for instance) are added consecutively, one per time step. It describes growth of crystals in 3D by cellular automata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure there are better ways, but in case you did not find it, here is a faster way:

```
for i in range(A.shape[1]-1):
  A = np.where((A==0)&(np.pad(A,((0,0),(1,0)))[:,:-1]==7),7,A)
```

output:

```
[[0 0 7 7 7 7]
 [0 0 0 0 5 0]]
```

Comment: Ehsan, thank you very much :) I think this is it. Sorry for not being more specific from the beginning.